# Не могу установить pip для Python 3.7

Tags: python, ssh, pip

У меня в системе есть python 2.6.6, я установил новую версию питона 3.7.2 (вот по такому примеру http://p97889rm.beget.tech/articles/8-ustanovka-python-3-7-na-centos-7.html). Версию 2.6.6 удалять не стал (т.к. прочитал, что это не рекомендуется)

Возникла необходимость установить pip для версии питона 2.6.6 он ставится нормально, а для 3.7.2 при попытке выполнить

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O - | python3.7
```

получаю различные предупреждения:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

И в конце

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
```

Можете подсказать, как установить pip на версию python 3.7.2?

Comment: `easy_install pip` / `python3 -m easy_install pip`

Comment: Вас не смущает что Вам нужен python3-pip ????

Comment: Pip даже если установится, с него толку не будет, поскольку твоя инсталляция питона не содержит модуль `ssl`. Питон собирал сам из исходников? Тогда смотри лог команды `make`, там ошибки при сборке пишутся. Скорее всего, линковал с либой  OpenSSL не той версии, либо ещё что.

Comment: Да, там была ошибка про OpenSSL, я поставил питон 3.6, он нормально поставился

Answer (score 4):

У меня возникала похожая проблема на Ubuntu и я решил её  по такому принципу:

```
yum install python3.7 python3.6 python3-pip
python3.7 -m pip install pip
```

И в дальнейшем при обращении к pip на версии 3.7 нужно писать так:

```
python3.7 -m pip install package
```

По шагам:

1. Ставим python3 - то есть 3.6
2. Ставим python3.7
3. Ставим python3-pip - то есть для версии python3.6
4. С помощью python3-pip - ставим pip для python3.7

Comment: А симлинк подменить в /usr/bin на 3.7 не проще?

Comment: @Andrey в моём случае нет, использую докер и настройка происходит один раз во время сборки, после чего он лежит себе на сервере и я к нему больше не прикасаюсь) Не вижу смысла в этом;)

Comment: Поменять докер файл и пересобрать крайний слой.... проблем то....